# Create Configuration Screen for Office 365 Outlook Add-In

Tags: javascript, configuration, office365, outlook-addin

I am working on creating a Office 365 Add-In that will work for both Outlook for Desktop and the Web version. I want a way to let users store some settings that will be then used by the ADD-IN so that the ADD-In can pass that to the remote service.

1. When someone installs this add-in, how can I create a UI for the user to enter some details like a company number and username.
2. How can I use above settings in JavaScript of my Add-In?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Dialog API to open dialog boxes in your Office Add-in. This article provides guidance for using the Dialog API in your Office Add-in.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins

You can set data in mailbox 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/metadata-for-an-outlook-add-in